# Fetching html form data in django

Tags: python, django

I have created one html form for my web application. Now I want to fetch data for further validation on submit the form in DJANGO. So how can I do this. I have attached my html form code below. Actually, I can get the data by the request.POST.get('field_name') method but I want to get data in the single object. Also I want to create seprate python file for validation. So how can I redirect on that file.

```
<form action="/contact_form_data_insert" name = "contact_us_form" id = "contact_us_form" method="POST">
    <div class="bg-transperent container mt-6">
        <div class="bg-transperent container">
            <div class="row bg-transperent">

                <div class="col-lg-6 bg-transperent contact_field">
                    <div class="form-outline my-2 px-2" >
                      <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" class="form-control form-control-lg-border-0" placeholder = "Your Name"/>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-lg-6 bg-transperent contact_field">
                    <div class="form-outline my-2 px-2" >
                      <input type="text" id="contact_company" name="contact_company" class="form-control form-control-lg-border-0" placeholder = "Your Company" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row bg-transperent">

                <div class="col-lg-6 bg-transperent contact_field">
                    <div class="form-outline my-2 px-2" >
                      <input type="tel"  id="contact_phone_number" name="contact_phone_number" class = "form-control form-control-lg-border-0" placeholder = "Phone Number">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-lg-6 bg-transperent contact_field">
                    <div class="form-outline my-2 px-2" >
                      <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" class="form-control form-control-lg-border-0" placeholder = "Email"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




        <div class="bg-transperent container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 bg-transperent contact_field ">
                        <div class="form-outline my-2 px-2" >
                          <input type="text" id="contact_subject" name = "contact_subject" class="form-control form-control-lg-border-0" placeholder = "Subject" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
           
        </div>


        <div class="bg-transperent container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 bg-transperent contact_field">
                        <div class="form-outline my-2 px-2" >
                            <textarea class="form-control form-control-lg-border-0" id="contact_question" name="contact_question" placeholder = "Your Question" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container bg-transperent">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 px-4">
                    <input type="submit" class = "btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block"style="color: white;font-family: serif; font-weight: bolder; "  value="SEND">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Django form in the backend for example login form has username and password fields
Don't use it in the front
Just make your own form in the front end with fields named username and password
Django of course can't tell if the data sent from Django form or custom form
So it'll treat it normally

For example

```
class LoginForm(Form):
 username = ...
 password = ...
 class Meta:
   fields = ('username', 'password')
```

Now in the backend

```
form = LoginForm (request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
```

The form only needs data named username and password from the front side

Comment: I know about django form but its like to create form using django. But i have already created my form using html. So now how can i do same process which we do on django form on my form data.

Comment: Use Django forms in the backend, in the front make your own form as you like just name your fields the same name they have in the backend

Comment: I understood your point well. But how can i targer my form in backend. Can you please explain me. And if possible can just give demo.

Comment: You only need to call it from your view, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

About using ***Django forms***, here's a quick demo... You can create a file within your `app` folder called `forms.py` and place the following inside of it.

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):  
     # You can also modify the field attributes from here if you wish to
     contact_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'contact_name', 'name': 'contact_name', 'class': 'form-control form-control-lg-border-0', 'placeholder': 'Your Name'}))

     # You can take the same approach for the other text & email input fields below
     contact_company = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={...}))
     contact_phone_number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={...}))
     contact_subject = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={...}))
     contact_email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={...}))

     # Textarea field
     contact_question = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'id':'contact_question', 'name': 'contact_question', 'class': 'form-control form-control-lg-border-0','placeholder': 'Your Question', 'rows': '5'}))

     # Can create any method in here to handle a specific process if the form is valid
     def save(self):
         pass
```

From your `views.py` file within the same `app` folder:

```
from .forms import ContactForm  # Importing the custom form you created

# Now let's say I want to pass it to a specific view to allow a user to submit his/her information...
def contact_form_view(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
          form = ContactForm(data=request.POST)

          if form.is_valid():
               # Do something here to process and save the form data
               form.save()
          else:
               print(form.errors)
     else:
          form = ContactForm()
     
     return render(request, 'contact_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Now, within your `html` template, you could just replace the respective `input` fields with the `form object` fields. For example:

```
<form method="POST" ...>
     # Where you have these fields
     <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" class="form-control form-control-lg-border-0" placeholder = "Your Name"/>

     # Just replace with... (i.e.: contact_name as above)
     {{ form.contact_name }}

     # Apply the above with the other respective fields.
</form>
```

I trust you already know how to set up your `url` for the `view`. In a nutshell, that's an approach you could take.

I do recommend that you read the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/) for more information on the Django forms though.